# Is it possible to reduce the writing of code to take out for example: ref.read(countProvider.notifier) - in build method?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

For example, to access the increment and decrement methods we can write as follows:

```dart
onPressed: () {
    ref.read(countProvider.notifier).increment;
},

onPressed: () {
    ref.read(countProvider.notifier).decrement;
},
```

**Can we reduce it if we write in the build method like this:**

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final countProvider = ref.watch(countProvider)
    final countNotifier = ref.read(countProvider.notifier)

onPressed: () {
    countNotifier.increment;
},

onPressed: () {
    countNotifier.decrement;
},
```

**as if to put the reference to the notifier in the build method**

Everything works with this approach, but is this the right solution if Remi does not recommend to put ref.read in the build method

Comment: Did you get the code shortened?

Comment: Yes thank you! You gave me more confidence

Comment: Mark the answer as correct so it can help others :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything will work fine, exactly in that order. You're watching the condition and then reading it. So the `countNotifier` will always have the current value.

However, it is better to take advantage of it:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final countProvider = ref.watch(countProvider);
    final countNotifier = ref.watch(countProvider.notifier); // changed to watch

    onPressed: () {
        countNotifier.increment;
    },

    onPressed: () {
        countNotifier.decrement;
    },
}
```